# How to stop modal code from executing until it gets triggered in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have a component X in react where I am triggering a modal on a button click.

```
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        componentName={<FormComponent />}
      />
```

The FormComponent is calling a fetch api in its useEffect(). The issue is that whenever I am using this X component anywhere, the fetch api gets triggered even before the button to trigger the modal is clicked.

I tried something like this to conditionally render the modal code but it's causing a noticeable delay for the modal to show up and for some reason the page just hangs when i close the modal

```
{
isOpen && <Modal
           isOpen={isOpen}
           componentName={<FormComponent />}
           />
}
```

I need a way to call the api only when the modal gets triggered. The component X is getting called multiple times in a page and this is causing the api to hit several times on page load itself.

Thanks

Comment: Try `<Modal isOpen={isOpen} componentName={isOpen && <FormComponent />}/>`

Comment: It's hard to predict the situation until I see the code inside the `<FormComponent />` but you are avoiding rendering until the user clicks on the button so obviously when you try to open it's making an API call and it's causing delay, but why the page freezes not sure maybe you are cleaning dependent resources.